# Decrease the sensitivity on Capacitive Touch breakout?

Tags: electronics, firmware

I have this capacitive touch sensor: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-capacitive-touch-sensor-breakouts/overview

And it is WAY too sensitive for my purpose. I want to have a conductive panel on a jacket that when you touch the panel of conductive fabric, something happens. But this sensor is sensing my touch from about an inch away, and I need it to be way less sensitive so that it doesn't sense my skin through the jacket.

I'm really completely at a loss on how to change the sensitivity. I read the data sheet and it said to change Cs. But how do I do that? I assume I literally stick a physical capacitor somewhere? But I can't imagine where. I'm finding all this stuff about firmware and I just have no idea how to go in and change any settings or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Adafruit provides the full schematic of each sensor board.  The capacitors on the board should be marked as C1, C2, and so forth.

Capacitors in parallel add:

```
EQ 1. Ct = C1+ C2 + C3
```

However, capacitors in series add as reciprocals:

```
EQ 2. 1/Ct = 1/C1 + 1/C2 + 1/C3
```

You can easily experiment with adding a parallel capacitance.  Simply solder a small value capacitor in across the C1 capacitor listed in the schematics.

To lower the overall capacitance value, you'll need to replace the surface mount cap on the board since the board doesn't seem to have any pads to attach series capacitors.